# Using data from 2 queries in order to make a graph

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

I have three tables in MySQL. 
Staff with fields id, name, surname, telephone, adress, id_work.
Work with fields id, name.
Absence with fields id, name, id_staff. 
Also,I have the following queries:
Query 1

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM staff s 
INNER JOIN work w ON s.id_work = w.id 
LEFT JOIN absence a ON s.id = a.id_staff 
WHERE w.name='sales manager' 
AND a.name = 'disease' 
AND a.id_staff IS NULL;
```

Query 2

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM staff s, work w, absence a 
WHERE s.id=a.id_staff 
AND s.id_work=w.id 
AND w.name='sales manager' 
AND a.name='disease'.
```

As it seems, the first query is inverse of second query. I want to make a graph which seems the % of the staff who is active/inactive. I decide to use google graphs and especially 3D pie chart:
https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/piechart#making-a-3d-pie-chart
I try to connect mysql with javascript via Ajax but dont work
Do you nhave any other idea in order to make this graph using data from those queries

Comment: You didnt provide any info why its not working, no code, no errors, so I wouldn't hope too much that someone would be able to answer this and help you. Maybe you could start with some tutorial, this seems reasonable http://sophiedogg.com/creating-a-google-pie-chart-using-sql-data/ as a template.

Comment: Thanks about your answer